How to solve issues caused by Debian's outdated Texlive?
I am running a Debian server, which installs the following version of Texlive:
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.3.1/dev

Copyright 2018 ..... (truncated for brevity) ..... Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.

Compiled with libpng 1.6.36; using libpng 1.6.36
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.00

On my own machine, I'm using this:
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023)
kpathsea version 6.3.5

Copyright 2023 .....(truncated for brevity) ..... Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.

Compiled with libpng 1.6.39; using libpng 1.6.39
Compiled with zlib 1.2.13; using zlib 1.2.13
Compiled with xpdf version 4.04

This causes a ton of issues, such as:

\bfseries doesn't work properly with the siunitx package
Chunked content using \\* doesn't work properly in longtable
etc.

What can I do to overcome this, short of fixing the outdated Debian package? Some options I've gathered from looking on the site:

Copy the .sty. files for relevant packages from my local into the server to override the buggy ones.
Install vanilla version directly from TUG (https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html).
Somehow find a way to use 2023 (which I don't know how to do).

What is the best practice for dealing with this? I'm aware I can use \listfiles to log all my dependencies, but I'm unsure what I'm supposed to do with that.

don't do (1). you will introduce more bugs and incompatibilities. (2) is the only sensible option. (3) i don't understand.

Which version of debian are you running? The current stable (bookworm) has texlive from 2022-2023.

Use (2). Install the vanilla version is not as easy as use apt, but it works fine in Debian. The other option is use apt, but only apt. You will suffer from the horrible feeling of not being at the cutting edge, really you will not miss anything essential by using the Debian stable packages.

Depending on how stable you need your server to be, you could switch to running Debian Testing. This gives a reasonably up to date TeXLive installable by apt.

Go for (2). Be aware, however, of potential problems (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/676877, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/673389, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/676187 ). There is also an entry on Debian's wiki (https://wiki.debian.org/TeXLive), which may help (it also may be slightly out of date, but the principles should be good). See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/678710 for possible ways to install

Best practice is somehow opinion based, but (1) usually wouldn't be a good idea. New versions of several packages depend on using new LaTeX kernels and l3 layer in the kernel or new versions of other packages. Even new versions of the engines could be required (e.g. to have primitive \expanded). For (2) see How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?.
